# How to use proxies with Indy TIdWhois?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I cannot figure out how to use proxies with `TIdWhois`. Does anybody have a clue for me?

Following Remy's description, I use the following code:

```
w:=TIdWhois.Create(nil);
p:=TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Create(nil);
io:=TIdIOHandlerStack.Create(nil);
p.Host:=<proxy-ip>
p.port:=<proxy-port>
io.TransparentProxy:=p;
w.io:=io;
w.host:=<whois-server>
w.port:=43;
w.WHoIs(<domain>);
```

Monitoring the ports, it still use my real IP for the request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/201008/1008254632.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy 10 natively supports two types of proxies:

- HTTP, via the
  `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` component.
- SOCKS 4/4a/5, via the `TIdSocksInfo`
  component.

To use either one of them, you need to:

1. Assign a
   `TIdIOHandlerSocket`-derived component, such as `TIdIOHandlerStack`, to the
   client's `IOHandler` property.
2. Assign the desired proxy component to the `TIdIOHandlerSocket.TransparentProxy` property, set its `Host` and `Port` properties to the Host/Port of the desired proxy server, and enable it accordingly (via the `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Enabled` or `TIdSocksInfo.Version` property).
3. Set the client's `Host`
   and `Port` properties to the Host/Port of the target server, and then `Connect()` and use the client normally.

Comment: I updated my question, added an example which is following your description, but it wont work for me.

Comment: @Softtouch you are not setting the `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Enabled` property to true. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to set enabled to true, did not work either. But it worked when I use TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.create(w) instead of TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.create(nil), and same for TIdIOHandlerStack.Create.

Comment: @Softtouch the choice of `Owner` has no effect whatsoever on how the components operate. It only controls memory management, nothing else. If you set a nil `Owner`, make sure you `Free()` the component after using it..

Comment: Then I have no clue anymore. Without setting the owner, it does not work for me. It only use the proxy when I set the owner.

Comment: @Softtouch you should set the `Owner` anyway, as practice in good memory management. But it has no effect on your issue. The code you showed is fine, other than it was missing the `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Enabled` assignment. I can't say why it doesn't work without an `Owner`, I will have to debug it. Which versions of Delphi and Indy are you using?

Comment: sorry, I am a moron, I forgot to mention I use Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, with the provided Indy components. I also use the firemonkey framework, not vcl.

Comment: @Softtouch that doesnt change anything I said.